# Breaking Text Block In A DIV To Screen Height

Tags: html, css

Ideally I want to have columns that when displayed are only visible for that screen that you are on so that the one screen page that is visible will show the full columns (no matter how many across) to the height of the current screen.

These columns then break the content automatically on to the next page if the content is too long for that single screen so that a user could effectively just page down to see the next block of columns.

The css code I am using to make (two) columns with right now  (that is responsive) is below:

```
.resp-column {
  padding: 1em;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 1em;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
.resp-column {column-count: 1;}
}
```

So... this css works fine for two columns and responsive but I know that when I have two very long columns of text they are a pain to read on any device unless they break per current screen length.

HOW DO I : break the content on screen length automatically when not on @media screens?

I tried adding > `height: 100vh;` < into .resp-column and it did not work... 
it only created multiple horizontal columns.

Thanks for any and all help in advance.

Comment: Couldn't figure it out yet but here is a link with useful stuff: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/ You might want to check out the column breaks section.